# Install driver using InstallShield

Tags: installshield, device-driver

I need to create an InstallShield 12 project that installs a driver on WinXP or higher. How can I do it using InstallShield 12?

Comment: What kind of driver? What kind of project? (DIFx supports only certain kinds, and that's what MSI-based projects use) How do you install this manually? That's how an InstallScript project might install it.

Comment: PlugAndPlay driver DIFx is ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What we usually do is write a DLL (in C or C++) which uses SetupAPI calls (SetupDiXXX and UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevices) to do all the installation work.

And then, have the installer script(IS, Inno, Wise) make calls into this DLL.

Answer (score 3):

In 2012 Spring Pro (I can't speak to earlier versions), you can simply create a new feature with the desired components (note: use one component for the 64-bit side, and another component for the 32-bit side, both under the same feature).  For each of the driver components, go into the Advanced Settings section in the tree view control under the component, then into the Device Driver settings, and on the Common tab, check the "This component includes a device driver" box.  Under Runtime Options using DIFx 2.10, set any desired configuration bits, like "Always overwrite any existing device driver", and then at the bottom of the Common tab, be sure to set the appropriate architecture/bittage.  Then just let it install -- InstallShield plus DIFx 2.10 take care of everything automagically.

At least, this worked just fine with our custom, signed, WinUSB-based driver.  It was a lot harder figuring this out then actually doing it.

Answer (score 2):

I simple way is to wrap [dpinst](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff544842%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Use the [command line flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff544775%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to suppress a gui and read the [return code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff544790%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to figure out if the install worked correctly